# Compute Loan Balance for a specific month (period) on an amortized loan

Tags: accounting, financing

I'm looking for is a method that will allow me to compute the **Loan Balance**  value for a specific period (month) in the amortization table **without having to compute all of the values before it.**

Let's say: your bank loan of 100000$ at the rate of 10% with annual rate compounded **monthly** and for a maturity of a 10 years.

So we have following information:

PV = 100000$,
Time (or n) = 10,
Frequency (#) = 12 (monthly),
Rate (r) = 10% or 0.1.

We should find *66th* month Loan Balance value without establishing whole table. Please do not suggest to calculate with **Future Value (FV of annuity)** formula replacing Time (n) = by 66 (month that we want to find value)

Comment: Why reject an essential part of the only possible solution?

Comment: This looks more like a homework problem than an actual personal money problem faced by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
PV = principal
i  = periodic rate
m  = number of periods
d  = periodic payment

d  = PV i (1 + 1/((1 + i)^m - 1))
```

the balance `b` remaining in month `x` is

```
b  = (d + (1 + i)^x (i PV - d))/i
```

Applying your figures

```
  PV = 100000
  i  = 0.1/12
  m  = 10*12

∴ d  = 1321.51

  x  =  66
∴ b  =  57276.53
```

*Check: final balance*

```
  x  =  120
∴ b  =  0
```

***Formulae***

Formula for periodic payment - [loan payment formula](http://financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html)

[image]

Formula for loan balance - [inhomogeneous difference equation](http://people.math.aau.dk/~cornean/IMM_E12/notes2011a.pdf) (Arne Jensen, Aalborg Uni.)

[image]